# lmfit stderr in parameter’s value as mathematical formula

Tags: python, math, theory, lm, lmfit

I try to figure out how I can write the parameter’s stderr of lmfit as a mathematical formula. [Performing Fits and Analyzing Outputs](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html) (*Uncertainties in Variable Parameters, and their Correlations*) from lmfit lists three components of the function:

1. inverted Hessian
2. reduced chi-square
3. increase in chi-square by reduced chi-square

Reading the source code of [LM.py](https://gist.github.com/geggo/92c77159a9b8db5aae73) (**wrong source code** - see comment from M Newville) you can find the python-implementation of the technique in rows 100 to 126. It contains all of the three components as *diagonale (1)* and *sigma (2)* and combines them to *parerr* - the code I want to rewrite as mathematical formula.

Right now my approach looks like this [with θ_p as parameter in vector of parameters θ = (θ_0, …, θ_p) ∊ ℝ_p ]:

[image]

I am unsure about the interpretation of 3.

Comment: If you want to know how lmfit does this, perhaps look at its source code, say at https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/21d3e6b008a74a4aaa9e97eae32f76a316f18671/lmfit/minimizer.py#L833   To do step 3, the covariance matrix is simply multiplied by reduced chi-square.

Comment: So it is just σ = χ_red^2 * H^(-1), thanks a lot for the explaination!

Comment: Not 100% sure I know what you're looking for, but I think you might need a square root in there.  That is, standard errors are the square roots of the diagonal components of the covariance.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explaination, that was exactly what I was looking for. As you said and https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/21d3e6b008a74a4aaa9e97eae32f76a316f18671/lmfit/minimizer.py#L850 shows, it should be σ(θ)=(χ_red^2*H(θ)^(-1))^0.5.